# MYSQL upgrade GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

we have upgraded `MYSQL` database;

```
SELECT l.subscriberid AS subscriberid FROM email_list_subscribers AS l, email_queues AS q 
            WHERE q.recipient = l.subscriberid AND q.queueid = 2343 AND queuetype = 'send' 
            AND l.listid IN (31) GROUP BY l.emailaddress HAVING COUNT(l.emailaddress) > 1
```

and now we get

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'emailmarketer.l.subscriberid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

what can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.emailaddress,
       GROUP_CONCAT(l.subscriberid) AS subscriberids
FROM email_list_subscribers l JOIN
     email_queues  q 
     ON q.recipient = l.subscriberid 
WHERE q.queueid = 2343 AND queuetype = 'send' AND
      l.listid IN (31)
GROUP BY l.emailaddress
HAVING COUNT(l.emailaddress) > 1;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.
- This returns a list of the subscribers for each email.
- If there are duplicates, you might want `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.subscriberid)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. Why my select works in v5.6 and not 5.7?

Comment: @mbrc . . . The reason this doesn't work is because of the SQL mode.

Comment: Can I just enable sql mode for sql 5.7?

Comment: @mbrc . . . You should fix the query rather than using (mis)features in MySQL that produce indeterminate results.

Comment: I think I found it https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/